# AWS Lambda - Unable to access the files and folder from lambda layer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

I have a lambda function written in .NET 6 to which I have attached a lambda layer which is a zip file with many JSON files inside different folders in it.

I want to read each JSON file in my lambda function.

When I do this I get an error saying **Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/geojson-files/UK.json'**:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "geojson-files", "UK.json");
var geojson = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
```

I also tried `/opt/geojson-files/UK.json`. But still unable to read the file.

Is there any way to read the file in a lambda function from a lambda layer?

Comment: Lambda layer zip archives are extracted into `/opt`.

Comment: Yeah. I have mentioned in the questions that I checked the /opt folder as well but was unable to find it there. Based on my question can you please suggest the path 
 on which I should be doing  File.ReadAllTextAsync

Comment: Double check that your Layer was created correctly and that your Lambda function is configured correctly to use the layer. Then enumerate the contents of `/opt` and see if that helps you debug the issue.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your help. I have posted the solution for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jarmod for his suggestion in the comments to enumerate the contents of `/opt`

I iterated over the `/opt` folder and could get the root cause of my problem i.e. unable to read files from the lambda layer.

I zipped the contents of `geojson-files` from inside that folder. So when I enumerated `/opt`, I could directly see `/opt/UK.json` file. So then I zipped the `geojson-files` folder and now I can see `/opt/geojson-files/UK.json` file.